# Is there a way to send a svn revision as a link in windows

Tags: windows, svn

our dba wants to change from recieving files as attachements to some sort of link to a specified revision in svn.
I suggested copying e.g.

svn --force export `<svn url`>@`<revision`>

to a dos prompt but text has to be manually assembled the sender and the DBA want's to avoid any typing.

I've looked through tortoise svn but can't find anything to support this, has anyone any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: just use the `svn://` syntax no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Subversion served via http, you're probably aware that you can browse the leaf revision by just pointing your browser to the svn url, e.g.

```
http://dotnx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dotnx/trunk/index.html
```

In order to access a specific revision you must insert `!svn/bc/REVISION` in your URL right after the repository, e.g.

```
http://dotnx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dotnx/!svn/bc/11/trunk/index.html
```

However, I'd suggest that you setup a proper repository browser, such as [viewvc](http://www.viewvc.org/)

Comment: Thanks. Installed viewvc which allows me to send links in the checkout view, exactly what our DBA wants.